# Move bootstrap columns up/down with col-push or pull

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I keep trying and trying and can't seem to get this without resorting to hidden-xs and duplicating my markup. The goal is to have full-width columns swap positions as follows:

Mobile:

```
[B]

[A]
```

Desktop:

```
[A]

[B]
```

I've tried

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-push-12">B</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-pull-12">A</div>
```

and every other variation I can think of but it just seems to push it off the sides...

Here is my totally not-working demo! http://www.bootply.com/ZgUJmBeKL4

Comment: Look at my answer and try the fiddle resizing the browser... Let me know

Comment: See my comment attached to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/5PCXj/

refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

you can use also ***table-row-group***  display property to put elements between ***table-header-group*** and ***table-header-group***

```
.first{display: table-header-group;}
.second{display: table-footer-group;}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .first{display: table-footer-group;}
   .second{display: table-header-group;}
}

<div class="col-md-12 col-md-push-12 first">B</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-pull-12 second">A</div>
```

Comment: Can I see your broken code? I think I should help you